# What are the components of a JavaScript Browser Side Framework/Solution Architecture?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

What are the components of a JavaScript browser side web application architecture? I am aware of the following items and looking to for the most complete list.

1. Normalized DOM API that behaves the same in all browsers.
2. Ajax Wrapper offering a better API to access the XHR object.
3. Template engine to make writing widgets easier.
4. Module loading system.
   ... etc?

What are essential components of a client side JavaScript Architecture for building complex web apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list you provided is pretty good. Here's some additional considerations

**1)** A good framework has good file structure and namespacing practices. One way that I am particularly fond of organizing your library might have the following files/paths:

```
a. projectRoot/js/lib/ams/xml/Document.js
b. projectRoot/js/lib/ams/util/util.js
c. projectRoot/js/lib/ams/util/base64.js
d. projectRoot/js/lib/ams/util/HashMap.js
```

Which would define the following classes and namespaces

```
a. ams.xml.Document: Class definition
b. ams.util: Namespace definition. Use this file to put functions on a NS, such as ams.util.toArray(). Technically, this could/should go right in the 'ams' folder, but since there are other things on the 'util' namespace, a folder is created. For an example of a namespace definition without
c. ams.util.base64: Namespace definition. Use this file to put functions on a NS, such as ams.util.base64.encode(). Since there are no namespaces below base64, no folder is necessary.
d. ams.util.HashMap: Class definition on the util namespace
```

**2)** Standardize the way you define classes to assist with inheritance. I personally prefer the psuedo-classica model with prototypal inheritance, with the use of an inheritance helper function such as:

```
ns.inherits = function(childCtor, parentCtor) {
  function tempCtor() {};
  tempCtor.prototype = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.superclass = parentCtor.prototype;
  childCtor.prototype = new tempCtor();
  childCtor.prototype.constructor = childCtor;
};
```

this would be used as such:

```
ns.BaseClass = function(arg){
    this._privateProp = arg;
};
ns.BaseClass.prototype._privateProp = null;

ns.Class = function(arg1, arg2){
    ns.Class.superclass.constructor.call(this, arg1);
    this.publicProp = arg2;
};
ns.inherits(ns.Class, ns.BaseClass)
ns.Class.prototype.publicProp = null;
```

**3)** Definitely get a good module loading system in place. You do not want to have to maintain a flat list of javascript files and their dependencies. A good one to use is in google's "closure library". It might take a bit to get set up, but it's well worth the effort. Check out "plovr" to make development with closure a bit easier. The beauty with closure is that there is a compiler which lets you create a static js file with the dependencies resolved, and the files concatenated and minified. The syntax is nice too, for instance continuing from **2)** above:

*in ./ns/Class.js*

```
goog.provide('ns.Class');
goog.require('ns.BaseClass');

ns.Class = function(arg1, arg2){
...
```

The closure framework will also make sure that 'ns' exists before you try to define 'Class' on it ( since it knows you are going to provide ns.Class), thus preventing a null object error.

**4)** If you are planning on putting a lot of logic on the client, you should think about creating some form of model class to assist with synchronization of your view with the back-end server state. A lot of people refer to this as MVC, but that is a bit of a misnomer as it typically refers to a system based around PHP and static page generation. For more modern complex javascript-based web apps, an MVVM structure is more appropriate.

**5)** Depending on how much html creation you want the framework to be responsible for, if you plan on creating things like Containers, Panels, Buttons, etc, you might want to build your own event system which skips the DOM. Imagine you had a base Panel class, which provided additional functionality around a simple DIV. Then you called Panel::add and gave it an instance of a Button (which managed a BUTTON **or** a DIV with click handlers - same thing). You might want to dispatch an 'add' event from the panel, but there is no need for the DOM if you want to do that. Only other instances of your framework would know how to handle the 'add' anyways. In reality, you probably only need to capture the DOM events (maybe make a domEvent util...) and then dispatch events within your framework. Why would you do this? SPEED and control. Dom events are bulky, expensive, and behave differently from one browser to the next. Besides, it's nice to be able to express events in a way that is not tied to the DOM

**6)** Think about the difference between your framework (which presumably will be shared across several projects) and a project using it. They probably should have different namespaces and file structure. Following the namespaceing conventions above would leave you with something like

```
projectRoot/js/src/app/MainPanel.js
projectRoot/js/src/app/ViewPort.js
projectRoot/js/src/app/...
```

**Hope all this helps. Good luck!**